# Windows Live photo gallery deleted my whole desktop!

Tags: windows-7, windows-live, windows-photo-gallery

I just tried the new version of Windows Live Photo Gallery. I double-clicked on a photo on my desktop and noticed that Photo Gallery added the desktop folder to the gallery.
I didn't like it and I wanted to remove Desktop from the list of folders that are part of the collection.

I right-clicked on it and chose "Remove from collection" (I'm using the Italian version so the menu choice might not be exactly spelled like that) but then **all the icons on my desktop disappeared**!

And there is no trace of them in recycle bin! I managed to do "Undelete" on desktop's right-click menu but it restored only one file. Both user's and shared desktop have been deleted!

How can I restore the desktop folder? As far as I know, System restore doesn't help with deleted files, but I can try for sure!

Fortunately, I never hit "remove from collection" on my real pictures directory :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do [System Restore](http://lifehacker.com/5466794/the-complete-guide-to-windows-system-restore-its-better-than-you-remember) to restore your system to a time before this happened.

Comment: As shown in my previous comment, I didn't need to restore EVERYTHING, but just the affected directory. Anyway, your answer is correct so +1 and MARK. Thank you, harrymc

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that everything was realy deleted? I';ve had problems with icons dissappeareing on windows 7. Try right clicking on the desktop and making sure that view->show desktop icons is checked.

Comment: I'm sure. Anyway I managed to restore everything. The system restore idea was correct,but I didn't need to restore everything. Just right-clicking on the desktop folder from user folder and restore a previous version of it. Thanks to you anyway.